# Почему расстояние высчитывается по разному?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

На сайте используется 2 api - один для фронта другой для бекенда. В обоих высчитывается расстояние от точки до точки. Но результат разный.

Примерный запрос:

Во фронте:

```
ymaps.route(['Казань','Москва']);
```

В бекенде:

берем координаты с помощью

```
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=Москва&format=json
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=Казань&format=json
```

И считаем расстояние:

```
https://api.routing.yandex.net/v1.0.0/distancematrix?origins=55.753215,37.622504&destinations=55.798551,49.106324&mode=driving&apikey={{ваш ключ}}
```

И в итоге получаем разные дистанции

в js - 823553

через http - 821250

может я должен что то добавить в параметры чтоб считалось расстояние по другому? или есть другой апи которого я не знаю?

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что JS API и HTTP API Матрицы маршрутов используют немного разные алгоритмы для выбора оптимального маршрута. Из-за этого в некоторых случаях ответ может различаться.
Вторым фактором является время запроса - между запросами через JS и HTTP API могла измениться реальная дорожная ситуация.

Если для Вашего сервиса критично отобразить на карте тот же самый маршрут, что был получен на бекенде, можно использовать [HTTP API Маршрутизатора](https://tech.yandex.ru/routing/router/#start?from=SO). Этот API возвращает сразу и геометрию маршрута (полилинию), которую можно отобразить на карте.